# Configuring Java version for TeamCity

Tags: java, jvm, teamcity, jetbrains-ide, teamcity-9.0

We have installed TeamCity on an OpenSuse machine. the version of TeamCity is 9.1.3.

I have installed JDK 1.8 on the server but I am not using it as default Java. I want to update every Agent to build with new JDK (version 8) and if update was successful for all of agents then I will try to upgrade JDK for whole system.

I couldn't find an easy way for running an agent or project with specific JDK version. I am used to with Jenkins and there it was pretty easy to use different JDK for builds.

I looked at Team city documentation but couldn't find any real instruction how can we use an specific Java version for a project or agent.

Any help?

Comment: just create an env variable `JAVA_HOME=""` on each agent or confiruration params

Comment: Exporting only `JAVA_HOME` might not be enough, some of TeamCity agents I work with are not able to detect all the available JDKs on the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you are looking for is [this one](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/setting-up-and-running-additional-build-agents.html). As Senior Pomidor said its enough to specify that environment variable.

Running several jdk's on an agent to support builds with different java versions is described on [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html).

Comment: thanks @wemu for your answer. I saw those pages by myself.  The problem is that when I am checking Agent parameters there are some wrong agent parameter like JDK_16  /usr/java/latest which in this case the latest for my installation is jdk18. I want to find the place defining this and change it

Answer (score 3):

In your build configuration run three dots next to run button. Under the parameters tab, you can pass custom build parameters.

[image]

You can also have set environment bash script in your source code which overrides

```
#!bin/bash
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.JAVA_HOME' value='/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64']"
```

Include this script as part of build steps
[image]

```
file=%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/teamcityEnv.sh
echo "File : $file"
if [ -e "$file" ]
then
    echo "teamcityEnv file: '$file' found. Setting up the Env variables"
    sh $file
else
    echo "teamcityEnv not found. Skipping env setup"
fi
```